# CPanel/MySql ENUM sets default to ' '?

Tags: mysql, enums, default-value, cpanel

Hey guys I created a database column in my regular LAMP stack that seems to work great, the trouble is when migrating this into CPanel, it seems that my Default values in enum revert to ' ' or whitespace?

the command I used to create this column was

```
`status` ENUM('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

But it seems this doesn't actually happen.....
Is there an error in my syntax? A stupidity of CPanel?

What's going on here?

**EDIT**

It looks like it has something to do with the input button 
submitting a blank value? Anyone heard of this before?

Comment: Did you use phpMyAdmin to create the table?  Did you paste the `CREATE TABLE` into the `SQL` prompt or use the create table feature?

Comment: Pasted it from a sql file I created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MariaDB [test]> create table settest(attrib set('bold','italic','underline') DEF
AULT 'bold',color enum('red','green','blue') DEFAULT 'blue');



MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO settest VALUES('a','s');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.14 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                     |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'attrib' at row 1 |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'color' at row 1  |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM settest;
+--------+-------+
| attrib | color |
+--------+-------+
|        |       |
|        |       |
+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer to get a default is `NOT NULL DEFAULT 1` as per [1.3. ENUM](http://sql-info.de/mysql/gotchas.html)